# Find empty select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to locate empty form fields on the page.

For input text fields, I can use

```
input[value='']
```

For textarea fields, I can use

```
textarea:empty
```

What is the selector for finding select boxes whose selected option has an empty value?

Even though jQuery allows the selected option value to be retrieved with `.val()` the following does not work as a selector.

```
select[value='']
```

Comment: `input[value='']` is not going to find elements that have text filled in after load since the value attribute is not updated.

Comment: @epasc. yes you are right, but my purpose is setting focus on page load, so it works either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all select boxes whose selected option has an empty value:

```
$('select option:selected[value=""]')
```

And you may also check if selected option has an empty value:

```
$('select option:selected').val() === ""
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
    console.log('The option with text "' + $('select option[value=""]').text() + '" has no value.');
    
    $('select').change(function() {
        if ($('select option:selected').val() === "") { // or $(this).val() === ""
            console.log('This option has no value.');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="value1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

**Edit:**

Focus example:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.check').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.check {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" class="check" value="John Doe">
    
    <select class="check">
        <option value="value1">Opiton 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Opiton 2</option>
        <option value="value3">Opiton 3</option>
        <option value="" selected>Opiton 4</option>
    </select>
    
    <textarea class="check" rows="4">The cat was playing in the garden</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's your first approach that I am looking for.  I want to put the focus on the first empty input, select or textarea in a form on page load.  But your answer is not working for me, I suspect because it is the option being returned from the query, not the parent select.  If it was a single object, I could use .parent() but this is a comma separated multiple selector, to get the first empty field in DOM order (eg. input[value=''], select option:selected[value=''], textarea:empty)

Comment: Though it looks like a separate question, I edited the answer.  You can specify a class to all your form elements (input, select, textarea, etc.) and check their values if empty or not on page load. Focus on the first matched element with no value and then return false.

Answer (score 0):

Generic selector is probably not the best thing to use. I would select all the form elements and loop over them looking for the first one without a value

```
$(":input").each(function () {
  if (!this.value) {
    this.focus()
    return false
  }
})
```

You may need to add a check for checkboxes or radio buttons if you have those in your form.